# Parse Google JSON response in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, google-api

I'm trying to parse the JSON response form google. This is what I currently have:

```
Dim x As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim gJson As String = ""

Dim wClient As New WebClient
wClient.Proxy = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
gJson = wClient.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/...alt=json")
Dim results As gResponseClass = x.Deserialize(Of gResponseClass)(gJson)
```

`gResponseClass` as follows here: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/mbaMx1Aq)

I keep getting the following exception thrown:

`Invalid object passed in, member name expected. (6678): .... *the json response here* ...`

Is there any blatant problems or solutions I could implement?

**EDIT** :

The JSON response from google: [JSON Response](http://pastebin.com/NnymD8M6)

**EDIT**

Just for continuation purposes: the erros is cased indeed by the `"":` inside the `pagemap` node on facebook pages. I have resorted to calling a cleanup function as follows:

```
json = json.Replace(""""":", """page_id"":")
Return json
```

If anyone has a better way, please let me know!

Thanks again.

Comment: Have you looked at the JSON? Could you include it here?

Comment: @JonSkeet - hi Jon, cant believe you'd comment on my question! *shock* i have added the response as per the example searching for "flowers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is the bit of the JSON it's having trouble with:

```
"": [
 {
  "page_id": "66721388277"
 }
],
```

I'm not a JSON expert, but I can see why it might be surprised by that. As I mentioned, it can be parsed by [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) (at least as a `JObject`) so you might want to try using that instead.

---

**Original answer, still relevant**

The [`DeserializeObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject.aspx) method specifies:

> This deserialization method does not try to cast the root of the object graph to a specific type, as with the Deserialize method.

So I'd be surprised if it managed to cast to `gResponseClass` anyway. Have you tried using the [`Deserialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserialize.aspx) method instead?

(I'd have expected a compile-time error to be honest - do you have option strict and option explicit on?)

That may well not be the problem you're facing, but it's the first thing I'd look at anyway :) The JSON parses fine with JSON.NET.

Comment: thanks Jon, I will try JSON.NET. I have also tried `Deserialize` too - Updated my question.

Comment: wow. it was indeed the JSON response. It was the only place i didnt look because i _assumed_ , my fault that google json wouldnt be giving me hassles! changed the search parameter and works well with `Deserialize`. Do you have any tips for avoiding this issue?

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Ill resort to some sort of cleanup before I Deserialize.