# JSON "Invalid object passed in, member name expected"

Tags: json, parsing

One of our customers is having any issue with the web panel software we use, which parses various .json files. We and the customer have contacted the developers to have them look into this issue, but they stated everything was fine. However, their software is printing the error "Invalid object passed in, member name expected".

After searching this a bit, I confirmed my suspicion that this is indeed a formatting problem in the json file. I have pasted it into various formatters online, and all of them recognized it as being valid, so I am at a loss now.

Is there any decent way to hunt down syntax issues in .json files, as this is quite a long configuration.

http://pastebin.com/sqw5EKSf

Comment: what does this have to do with minecraft? Or object-reference? Show us some code?

Comment: This is for the groupinfo.json file that McMyAdmin (web panel) generates for Minecraft servers. Object reference was an incorrect tag, mistakenly put that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be this part:

On line 1024:

```
"": {
    "Members": [

    ]
```

Have a look at: [Parse Google JSON response in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7753326/511300)

Comment: Wow, very nice catch. I manually looked through that file twice and missed that both times. Excellent eye and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to paste the JSON in Firebug (the Firefox add-on) console and see if it complains. For example, if I paste this in the console:

```
var x = {"abc,
};
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id (line 2)
```

Let me know if this helps!